# How to count all possible $2^n$ subsets using the fundamental principle of counting?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinations

This is **NOT** a homework question.

How to use the fundamental principle of counting to derive the result that the total number of subsets of a set $A$ is $2^n$? $A$ has $n$ distinct elements.

I perceive that for building a subset from $A$, I have two choices for each element and $2^n$ choices for all $n$ elements considered together(this will contain all possible subsets of $A$). However, I want to write this down formally in a simple manner to prove the $2^n$ result that we have in elementary set theory.

What I want to use: [Fundamental principle of counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Induction should do, if a binary code isn't enough.

Comment: I want to use a method like the fundamental principle of counting.

Comment: What exactly is this "fundamental principle of counting"?

Comment: It is also called the rule of product or multiplication principle.

Comment: Um.... so far as I can tell the the argument "I perceive that for building a subset from A, I have two choices for each element and 2n choices for all n elements considered together"  *IS* the direct result of the fundamental principal of counting.

Comment: I wanted to write an argument that expresses the thought of all the elements being considered together as "events that are being done together".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $A = \{ a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \}$ of $n$ distinct elements, we may use the fundamental principle of counting to enumerate the total number of subsets of $A$ as follows:

For every element $a_i \in A$, we must consider two possibilities, that is, whether $a_i$ **is** or **is not** in a given subset. In other words, we must consider whether or not $a_1$ is in a given subset. Then, we must consider whether or not $a_2$ is in a given subset. Then, we must consider whether or not $a_3$ is in a given subset... and so on and so forth. We must consider these two possibilities for each of the $n$ elements in $A$, and there is always two such possibilities. Now, consider that each sequence of possible outcomes corresponds to a subset and vice versa. Hence, we may count the number of subsets by multiplying the number of possibilities at each step for each of the $n$ steps. In other words, we multiply $2$ by itself $n$ times. Hence, there are $2^n$ subsets.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what you said. Let $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, then there are $2$ choices -- whether $a_1$ is in the subset or not, then $2$ for whether $a_2$ is there or not, and so on for each $a_i$, $1\leq i\le n$. By the fundamental principle of counting, the total number of subset is precisely
$$\underbrace{2\times 2\times \dots \times 2}_{n\ \mathrm{times}}=2^n$$
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: If we *exclude* $\emptyset$ then we have $2^n - 1$ subsets. Any connection with Marin Mersenne primes? 